# How to set transaction timeout for Tasklet step in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a default timeout of 30 seconds configured at transaction manager level for all steps. Then for one particular step which needs a longer transaction, I configured TransactionAttribute for that step with transaction timeout set to 60 seconds. But this setting is being ignored. This long running step is also timing out after 30 seconds.

I debugged the spring code. In the step instance, I do not see the TransactionAttribute I set. I see the default one.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    transactionManager.setDefaultTimeout(30);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public TaskletStep processStep(ProcessAccountsTasklet accountsTasklet) {

    DefaultTransactionAttribute transactionAttribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
    transactionAttribute.setTimeout(60);

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processStep")
            .tasklet(accountsTasklet)
            .transactionAttribute(transactionAttribute)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job accountsJob() throws DuplicateJobException {

    final Job deleteDataJob = jobBuilderFactory.get("iipDeleteDataJob")
            .start(processStep())
            .build()
            .listener(customJobListener)
            .build();

    return deleteDataJob;
}

@Component
public class ProcessAccountsTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        //do stuff
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do such that just for the long running step the transaction timeout is 60 seconds and for all other steps it is 30 seconds?

Comment: `this setting is being ignored`: I'm not able to reproduce the case (See [this repo](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-sandbox/tree/master/so57191171)). Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue.